# How to sign executables for execution on WEC2013

Tags: certificate, x509certificate, windows-embedded-compact

For a WEC2013 platform with [enabled security loader](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/embedded/gg155001(v%3Dwinembedded.80)) I have created a self-signed certificate. The cert has the attributes

```
Key Usage: Digital Signature (80)
Enhanced Key Usage: Code Signing (1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.3)
```

The cert has been exported to a file `ciroots.p7b` and a PFX file. The `ciroots.p7b` has been added to the FILES folder of the WEC2013 platform as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/embedded/gg156296(v%3Dwinembedded.80)). The OS design built with the platform includes a copy of the file `ciroots.p7b`.

The PFX has been used to sign the file using the command

```
signtool -f /path/to/PFX -p ThePassword example.exe
```

This matches the [description](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/embedded/gg156011(v%3Dwinembedded.80)). The signtool command modified the .EXE. The resulting file is about 1kB larger then the original file.

After starting the OS design on the target and copying the signed .EXE to the target it should be possible to execute the program. But the start fails with the message:

> Cannot execute example.EXE

What did I miss in the steps described in the WEC2013 documentation? How can I prepare executables to run on a OS design with LVMOD enabled?

Although there were no error messages during the sign process it might be possible that I missed some important attributes. What are requirements for a certificate to be used for code signing with the LVMOD?

*Edit:*
Corresponding to Daniels comment I used signtool to verify the signed file. The certificate has been installed at the PC in the Trusted store (I was asked if I want to trust the cert). Running signtool as at [Using SignTool to Verify a File Signature](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/SecCrypto/using-signtool-to-verify-a-file-signature) I got the results:

```
 C:\Test>signtool verify  example.exe 
 SignTool Error: A certificate chain processed, but terminated in a root
         certificate which is not trusted by the trust provider.

 Number of errors: 1

 C:\Test>signtool verify /pa example.exe
 Successfully verified: example.exe

 C:\Test>
```

The first invocation fails, as the cited in the documentation for signtool:

> If the preceding example fails, it could be that the signature used a code-signing certificate. SignTool defaults to the Windows driver policy for verification.

Comment: Have you verified the signature? See here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/SecCrypto/using-signtool-to-verify-a-file-signature

Comment: I have verified the signature. Please see the update in the question.

Comment: The description at [MSDOCS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/embedded/gg156296(v%3Dwinembedded.80)) describes how *To add intermediate or root certificates to the Code Integrity certificate store*. To have trust the root issuer (in your case the signing cert itself as it is self-signed) must be installed to the trusted root certificate authorities. I looked around the documentation a bit but could not find a how to around WEC2013.

Comment: On **normal Windows** you can use the MMC.exe (certlm.msc) to import a root. Otherwise you must get a code signing certificate that was issued by a already trusted root CA.

Comment: Did you look it up? If you need more input have a look here for Root Store info: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/install/trusted-root-certification-authorities-certificate-store. Or this MSDN social thread that might help: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/2c4631f6-1758-46a6-95e7-2605c1748641/install-root-certificate-on-disk-image-using-platform-builder